# How to generate a list of repeated applications of a function to the previous result of it in IO context

Tags: haskell

As a part of a solution for the problem I'm trying to solve I need to generate a list of repeated application of a function to it's previous result. Sounds very much like *iterate* function, with the exception, that iterate has signature of

```
iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
```

and my function lives inside of IO (I need to generate random numbers), so I'd need something more of a:

```
iterate'::(a -> IO a) -> a -> [a]
```

I have looked at the [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/), but without much success.

Comment: Once you enter the IO monad, it sticks -- is my intuition anyway. Which is why I think the type you are _really_ looking for is `(a -> IO a) -> a -> IO [a]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your functions lives in IO, so the signature is rather:

```
iterate'::(a -> IO a) -> a -> IO [a]
```

The problem is that the original `iterate` function returns an infinite list, so if you try to do the same in IO you will get an action that never ends. Maybe you should add a condition to end the iteration.

```
iterate' action value = do
    result <- action value
    if condition result
        then return []
        else 
            rest <- iterate' action result
            return $ result : rest
```

Answer (score 5):

You can actually get a lazy iterate that works on infinite lists if you use the `pipes` library.  The definition is really simple:

```
import Pipes

iterate' :: (a -> IO a) -> a -> Producer a IO r
iterate' f a = do
    yield a
    a2 <- lift (f a)
    iterate' f a2
```

For example, let's say that our step function is:

```
step :: Int -> IO Int
step n = do
    m <- readLn
    return (n + m)
```

Then applying `iterate` to `step` generates a `Producer` that lazily prompts the user for input and generates the tally of values read so far:

```
iterate' step 0 :: Producer Int IO ()
```

The simplest way to read out the value is to loop over the `Producer` using `for`:

```
main = runEffect $
    for (iterate' step 0) $ \n -> do
        lift (print n)
```

The program then endlessly loops, requesting user input and displaying the current tally:

```
>>> main
0
10<Enter>
10
14<Enter>
24
5<Enter>
29
...
```

Notice how this gets two things correct which the other solutions do not:

- It works on infinite lists (you don't need a termination condition)
- It produces results immediately.  It doesn't wait until you run the action on the entire list to start producing usable values.

However, we can easily filter results just like the other two solutions.  For example, let's say I want to stop when the tally is greater than 100.  I can just write:

```
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P

main = runEffect $
    for (iterate' step 0 >-> P.takeWhile (< 100)) $ \n -> do
        lift (print n)
```

You can read that as saying: "Loop over the iterated values while they are less than 100.  Print the output".  Let's try it:

```
>>> main
0
10<Enter>
10
20<Enter>
30
75<Enter>
>>> -- Done!
```

In fact, `pipes` has another helper function for printing out values, so you can simplify the above to a pipeline:

```
main = runEffect $ iterate' step 0 >-> P.takeWhile (< 100) >-> P.print
```

This gives a clear view of the flow of information.  `iterate'` produces a never-ending stream of `Int`s, `P.takeWhile` filters that stream, and `P.print` prints all values that reach the end.

If you want to learn more about the `pipes` library, I encourage you to read the [`pipes` tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.0.1/docs/Pipes-Tutorial.html).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your resulting list must be in the IO monad, so iterate' must have produce an `IO [a]`, rather than '`[a]`'

Iterate can be defined as:

```
iterate (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
iterate f x = x : iterate f (f x)
```

so we could make an iterateM quite easily

```
iterateM :: (a -> m a) -> m a -> [m a]
iterateM f x = x : iterateM f (x >>= f)
```

This still needs your seed value to be in the monad to start though, and also gives you a list of monadic things, rather than a monad of listy things.

So, lets change it a bit.

```
iterateM :: (a -> m a) -> a -> m [a]
iterateM f x = sequence $ go f (return x) 
  where
    go f x = x : go f (x >>= f)
```

However, this doesn't work. This is because sequence first runs every action, and then returns. (You can see this if you write some `safeDivide :: Double -> Double -> Maybe Double`, and then try something like `fmap (take 10) $ iterateM (flip safeDivide 2) 1000`. You'll find it doesn't terminate. I'm not sure how to fix that though.

Comment: Unfortunately, your second version of `iterateM` won't terminate: for `sequence` to return, it has to run every `IO` action in the list first, and the list is infinite.

Comment: It's not lazy? Damn. I thought there might be a problem :(